# Como deletar uma linha específica de um arquivo?

Tags: c#, winforms

O meu objectivo é que quando o usuário retirar um item de um `Listbox`, o programa delete uma determinada linha de um arquivo.

---

Tenho este texto num arquivo `.txt`:

```
linha1
linha2
linha3
```

No `Listbox` contém o conteúdo do arquivo `.txt`, quero que quando o usuário delete uma linha especifica, delete também no arquivo.

Se o usuário deletar "linha2" o arquivo `.txt` deve ficar assim:

```
linha1
linha3
```

Tenho este código até agora:

```
//delete ListItemsBox Selected Item
private void ListItemsBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "MyTest.cs";
    if (ListItemsBox.SelectedItem.Equals("When Start"))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?All items will be deleted including all files!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ListItemsBox.Items.Clear();
            File.Delete(path);
            btnWhenStart.Show();
            End.Show();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
                    ListItemsBox.Items.Remove(ListItemsBox.SelectedItem);
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é que eu não sei como se faz e não percebo alguns tutoriais que me aparecem.

Comment: Editei a tua pergunta para ficar mais claro o que você quer. Obs.: No teu código só vai deletar a linha se for "When Start" e não a linha selecionada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim:

```
string line = null;
string line_to_delete = "the line i want to delete";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output")) {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
                continue;

            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Encontrei no StackOverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245243/delete-specific-line-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Para carregar o arquivo no `Listbox`, faça assim:

```
string caminho = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "foobar.txt";
listBox1.Items.Clear();

if (File.Exists(caminho))
{
     string[] linhas = File.ReadAllLines(caminho);
     listBox1.Items.AddRange(linhas);
}
```

Para remover a linha selecionada no `ListBox` do arquivo, você terá que ler linha por linha do arquivo e comparar com a linha selecionada do `ListBox`, feito isso, salve as modificações num arquivo temporário, no fim, substitua o arquivo original pelo modificado.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string caminho = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "foobar.txt";
    int indice = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

    if (indice != -1){
        string linha = listBox1.Items[indice].ToString();

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Deseja remover {0}?", linha),
                                                    "Warning",
                                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes){
            using (var input = File.OpenText(caminho))
            using (var output = new StreamWriter("tmpFoo.txt")){
                string linhaAtual;
                while ((linhaAtual = input.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    if (linhaAtual != linha){
                            output.WriteLine(linhaAtual);
                    } 
                }
            }

            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(indice); // Remove o item selecionado
            File.Delete(caminho); // Deleta o arquivo original
            File.Move("tmpFoobar.txt", caminho); // Substitui o original pelo modificado
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu consigo remover da list box eu quero é que a lihna saia do .cs